# Android How to add/configure Exchange setting programmatically?

Tags: android, exchange-server, configure

Is it me or I can't find any example of how to add/configure Microsoft Exchange programatically?

It seems like

AccountManager ::

```
addAccount (String accountType, String authTokenType, String[] requiredFeatures, Bundle addAccountOptions, Activity activity, AccountManagerCallback<Bundle> callback, Handler handler)
```

should do the work.
However, I can't figure out how for Microsoft Exchange account.
Could you point me to a simple working example code?

Thank you.

Comment: if you know how to configure VPN programmatically, I would like to know as well. I am assuming to program in Android 2.2+

Comment: Add another question, this is a different subject.

Comment: Can you please share how you did it. I need the same solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like it can't be done by applications.

you'll get the following exception:

`ERROR/AndroidRuntime(442): Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: caller uid xxxxx is different than the authenticator's uid`

you'll get this exception because the account manager verifies that the application that wrote the exchange authenticator (Google) is the same one that is creating the account. [here's a post](http://loganandandy.tumblr.com/post/613041897/caller-uid-is-different) that explains `AccountManager`'s logic in that case.

Comment: So, any idea to add programmatically an Exchange accounnt ?

Comment: Please share if you found a solution for this

Answer (score 0):

Android's AccountManager only adds sync based accounts, binding the provider and authenticator, helping authenticate credentials of the given account. Even after you would have taken care of the UID warning, you still need to populate the Exchange account settings properly, including those of sync look back etc. In short, you might need to be a system user app to work with the restricted content URI from email account.