# Is this possible to add and configure an exchange account programmaticaly

Tags: android, exchange-server, accountmanager, accounts

On android we can add an account manually through settings->Account&sync->add account->Corporate and then we fill the fields and add the account.

I want to do this programmatically. I searched on internet but did not find any way to do this.

I found two posts ( http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=21233  AND [Android How to add/configure Exchange setting programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4056043/android-how-to-add-configure-exchange-setting-programmatically) ), after which it looks like that it is not possible...But does any one know any way to do this?

We can programmatically open the screen settings->Account&sync->add account by intent Settings.ACTION_ADD_ACCOUNT. Can I somehow fill the fields too?

Is there any intent to do this? Or can I use account manager somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I did too encounter this problem and the only answer I ever got is NO for Android 3.0 and above, and NOT REALLY for 2.3 and lower.

- For platform 2.3 and lower you can call intent with parameters for the Exchange account creation screen, so all fields will be filled.

  ```
  //Gingerbread and lower
  ComponentName localComponentName = new ComponentName("com.android.email", "com.android.email.activity.setup.AccountSetupBasics");
  Intent exchangeIntent = new Intent("android.intent.action.MAIN");
  exchangeIntent.putExtra("com.android.email.AccountSetupBasics.username", mUserName);
  exchangeIntent.putExtra("com.android.email.AccountSetupBasics.password", mPassword);
  exchangeIntent.putExtra("com.android.email.extra.eas_flow", true);
  exchangeIntent.setComponent(localComponentName);
  exchangeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
  ```

  *(This code is based on an answer i found on stack exchange but i cant find it again for reference)*

  You must understand that this solution does not apply to devices that do not have the default eMail client.

  I consider this solution as a hack and not a real solution but this is what i'v found.
- From HoneyComb and onward the exchange account creation screen was changed and it does not get those parameters any more from the intent, so this solution does not apply and i could not found any other way to do it.
- Another solution that i have not implemented is to use a 3rd party email client which supply's needed API to create, delete or modify an exchange account

Hope i helped

Comment: Here is the link to where to <2.3 was from... for reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7901653/configure-exchange-email-account-via-android-api